# in how many ways can a subcommittee of five students be chosen if exactly three of them must be seniors and the rest juniors?

Tags: statistics, permutations, factorial

A committee is made up of 12 students. Five of them are seniors and the rest are juniors.

Comment: pick which three of the five are seniors.  Pick which two of the five are juniors...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there are $5$ seniors then there must be $7$ juniors. We can pick three seniors out of five in $^5 C_{3} = \binom{5}{3} = 10$ ways. Similarly, we can pick $5-3=2$ juniors from seven juniors in $^7 C_{2} = \binom{7}{2} = 21$ ways. Using **multiplication**, we have a total of $$21\times 10= 210$$ ways. Hope it helps.